# Paypal is enlarging my button. How can I resize my own style PayPal donate button to smaller size?

Tags: html, paypal

I appreciate your help in advance. PayPal is enlarging my 130px x 65px button to 300px x 150px. I've viewed the button on local browser and on Square Space editor and the result is the same. I also tried making the div smaller to contain the image but the size attributes are being ignored. Here is the html:

```
<div id="donate-button-container">

<div id="donate-button"></div>
<script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/donate/sdk/donate-sdk.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
<script>
PayPal.Donation.Button({
env:'production',
hosted_button_id:'2HR5GGV5XJRDQ',
image: {
src:'https://pics.paypal.com/00/s/YjdjOWYxN2UtNTYyNy00MjNkLTg1YmMtNDlkZjA4NTRmZjhi/file.PNG'
}
}).render('#donate-button');
</script>
</div>
```

Thanks again!

Comment: you could try setting max-width and max-height on your div, but keep in mind that your image might be skewed if proportions are not kept in the same range (aspect ratio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file `https://pics.paypal.com/00/s/YjdjOWYxN2UtNTYyNy00MjNkLTg1YmMtNDlkZjA4NTRmZjhi/file.PNG` is 300x150. Use a different image URL of a different size, if you want it to be different.